# Show that the relation is satisfied $A^2-\text{tr}\left(A\right)A+\det\left(A\right)I=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}\:$ such that $A^2=I\:$.

Show that the following relation is satisfied

$$A^2-\text{tr}\left(A\right)A+\det\left(A\right)I=0$$

I'm never really good at proving things.
I would probably start with changing the $A^2$ with the $I$ in the equation but other than that I'm not too sure how to show this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cayley Hamilton Theorem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the characteristic polynomial of a matrix?

Comment: In this simple case, direct evaluation is easy. Just compute every term in the left hand side and do some simple algebra.

Comment: oh yes, i couldn't remember the Theorem that related to this! i'll look more into it @CC0607

Comment: By the way, the condition $A^2 = I$ looks redundant.

Answer (score 6):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is

$$\chi_A(x)=\det(A-xI)=(a-x)(d-x)-cb=x^2-tr(A)x+\det(A)$$
Now use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to conclude.